# ProgressBar avance de acuerdo a los datos enviados

Tags: c#, windows-forms, progressbar

Estoy tratando que mi `ProgressBar` avance de acuerdo a los datos enviados al servicio. Todo funciona muy bien el problema es hacerle saber el usuario el progreso de los datos enviados usando el `ProgressBar`.

```
private void Enviar()
{
    OleDbDataReader read = MSAConnection.read(@"
                                            SELECT 
                                                Nombre
                                            FROM Persona");
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
    int count = 0;
    int countPro = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
            string nombre = Convert.ToString(read["Nombre"]);

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:7777/Services/Persona.svc/Persona/" + nombre);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            count = i;
            progressBar.Value = countPro++;
       }
    }
    read.Close();
}
```

Comment: Cual es el error? , por lo que veo te puede dar error aquí: `progressBar.Value = countPro++;` ya que tienes establecido que sea a un valor máximo de 100. Pero si `total` del ciclo `for` o del `reader` supera ese valor, te saltará una excepción

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo esto:

```
progressBar.Maximum = 100;
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Step = 1;
int porciento = 0;

 //....
 //Tu otro código....

 countPro++;
 porciento = Convert.ToInt32(( ( (double)countPro/ (double)total ) * 100.00 ));
 if (countPro >= total)
     progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
 else
     progressBar.Value = porciento;
```

> Otra cosa, como veo que tienes un `OleDbDataReader read` *Los lectores de datos en realidad son solo lectores de reenvío, no hay propiedades como `Count()` para devolver el recuento de las filas de resultados.* podrías sustituir el `total` en esta linea: `int porciento = Convert.ToInt32(( ( (double)countPro/ (double)total ) * 100.00 ));`  por el **total de registros de la consulta `totalfilas`** y al finalizar el ciclo `While` del `read` volver el `countPro = 0` de modo que cuando nuevamente recorra el ciclo `for` vuelva a iniciar desde cero el `ProgressBar` para cada registro del ciclo `for` mientras recorre el `While`

Puede cambiar la consulta a:

```
OleDbDataReader read = MSAConnection.read(@"
                                            SELECT 
                                                Nombre, count(*) as totalFilas 
                                            FROM Persona");

  //......
  //.......
  while (read.Read())
  {
        string nombre = Convert.ToString(read["Nombre"]);
        int totalFilas= Convert.ToInt32(read["totalFilas"]);
        //....
        //.....
        countPro++;
        porciento = Convert.ToInt32(( ( (double)countPro/ (double)totalFilas ) * 100.00 ));
        if (countPro >= totalFilas)
            progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
        else
            progressBar.Value = porciento;
 } 
 countPro = 0;
```

Eso le permitiría recuperar el recuento de filas. O usar algo como esto:

```
int totalfilas = 0; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM Persona", conn);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    totalfilas = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que cuando realizas procesos como lectura de base de datos, la interfaz de usuario puede bloquearse y quizás tu progress bar no se actualice.

Puedes realizar la obtención de datos utilizando un backgroundworker.

Declara una variable así en tu formulario:

```
BackgroundWorker  bgw = New BackgroundWorker();
```

En el constructor inicializas los valores del progressbar y asignas los eventos del backgroundworker:

```
public TuClase()
{
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
    bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
    bgw.ProgressChanged += bgw_ProgressChanged;
}
```

Creas un metodo sub así:

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     // aquí pones el codigo que carga los datos
    OleDbDataReader read = MSAConnection.read(@"
                                        SELECT 
                                            Nombre
                                        FROM Persona");
    // etc...

     //  y para actualizar el progress bar 
    bgw.ReportProgress(porcentaje);
    // donde porcentaje es una variable donde calculas el porcentaje
}
```

Luego agregas otro método donde directamente actualizas el progress bar:

```
private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    // aquí actualizas el progressbar, y cualquier otro control que tengas que actualizar
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Cuando quieras que inicie el proceso de descarga de datos usas :

```
private void BotonDeCarga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
}
```

Donde BotonDeCarga puede ser el botón que inicia la carga de datos.

Lo hice de memoria, no estoy seguro al 100% de que funcione tal cual pues lo escribí de memoria, pero en teoría debe de funcionar.